# Can the names of the broker channels in Spring Stomp websockets which are registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue") be changed?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

I have stumbled over this code countless time when reading on stomp and websocket for springboot

```
  @Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
}
```

or

```
    @Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue", "user");
}
```

which makes me wonder, if these channels are constant channels or they can be changed and if this are constant channels, what are their individual purposes. I have read so much article, but this would enable me understand websocket more.